# S3 boto3 function optimization

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, amazon-s3, boto3

I am using boto3 and I have a function that takes the last modified time(function parameter) of a s3 file and fetches all the files whole last modified time is either = function parameter or greater that function parameter.

This is my function and it works perfectly fine as well, but since there are millions of files in the s3 bucket, it takes a lot of time to execute. By any way, can we optimize how we fetch and filter data from s3 using boto3?

```
def get_data_from_s3_time_basis(self, last_modified):
        s3_bucket= self.s3.Bucket(self.S3_BUCKET)
        prefix = f"{self.s3_folder}/{self.s3_schema}/{self.sub_folder}/"

        logger.info(f"Fetching s3 files from {prefix} >= than timestamp {last_modified}")

        data_at_last_modified = []
        data_greater_than_last_modified = []

        for file in s3_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix):
            file_name = file.key.replace(prefix, '')

            if file.last_modified.replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc) == last_modified.replace(
                    tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc) and file_name != '':

                files_at_same_timestamp_row = (file_name, file.last_modified.replace(
                    tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc))

                data_at_last_modified.append(files_at_same_timestamp_row)

            if file.last_modified.replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc) > last_modified.replace(
                    tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc) and file_name != '':

                data_greater_than_last_modified_row = (file_name, file.last_modified.replace(
                    tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc))

                data_greater_than_last_modified.append(data_greater_than_last_modified_row)

        return data_at_last_modified, data_greater_than_last_modified, prefix
```

Tried multithreading so far as:

```
    def get_data_from_s3_time_basis_async(self, s3_bucket, prefix, data_at_last_modified, data_greater_than_last_modified, last_processed_time):
        for s3object in s3_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix):
            s3file = s3object.key.replace(prefix, '')
            s3_last_modified = s3object.last_modified.replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
            if s3_last_modified == last_processed_time and s3file != '':
                files_at_same_timestamp_row = (s3file, s3_last_modified)
                data_at_last_modified.append(files_at_same_timestamp_row)

            if s3_last_modified > last_processed_time and s3file != '':
                data_greater_than_last_modified_row = (s3file, s3_last_modified)
                data_greater_than_last_modified.append(data_greater_than_last_modified_row)

        return data_at_last_modified, data_greater_than_last_modified, prefix

    def get_data_from_s3_time_basis(self, last_processed_file_timestamp):
        s3_bucket = self.s3.Bucket(self.S3_BUCKET)
        prefix = f"{self.s3_folder}/{self.s3_schema}/{self.sub_folder}/"
        last_processed_time = last_processed_file_timestamp.replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

        data_at_last_modified = []
        data_greater_than_last_modified = []

        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1000) as executor:
            executor.map(self.get_data_from_s3_time_basis_async, s3_bucket, prefix, data_at_last_modified, data_greater_than_last_modified, last_processed_time)
```

Comment: Can you use S3 Inventory to get the list?

Comment: I can just use the boto3 library.

Answer (score 0):

A valid approach would be to retrieve the URLs for all your files, and then performing your desired operation in parallel over multiple files at once by either multithreading or asyncio.
A good introduction to parallel processing in python can be found [here](https://realpython.com/python-concurrency/).
If you'd rather use asynchronous IO (which I recommend for your use case), there is a well maintained boto3 variant called aibotocore that you can find [here](https://pypi.org/project/aiobotocore/).

Comment: This code is not downloading the s3 files, I am using multi threading for that.

This is just getting the file name and last modified time whole condition is satisfied.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but wouldn't you say you can split your files into batches and get the last modified time for the files in each batch in parallel, just as you would download the files in parallel?

Comment: agreed and I have tried the same and edited the question above as well with the findings @Alon Gadot